# XAML TwoWay Binding of RadioButton IsChecked

Tags: wpf, xaml, data-binding, radio-button

I'm trying to apply two way binding to a radiobutton in WPF. In XAML I have the following:

```
<RadioButton IsChecked="{Binding IsActive, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
```

and in the respective ViewModel I have

```
private bool _isActive;

public bool IsActive
{
    get { return _isActive; }
    set
    {
        _isActive = value;
        OnPropertyChanged("IsActive");
    }
}
```

Because I set mode to `TwoWay` I was expecting that as I toggle the radiobutton the IsActive property in the view model would get updated accordingly. However, `value` in `set` of `IsActive` is always true so the radiobutton is always on.

Am I misunderstanding the `TwoWay` property for a radiobutton, and if so how do i go about achieving the desired effect?

Comment: You are correct in your assumptions and the binding of IsChecked is TwoWay by default, so you don't need to specify it in the binding. There must be something else playing a part here, maybe another radio button is causing it to change. Can you use a breakpoint in the set of IsActive to see how the property value is being changed?

Comment: Don't have this problem with a CheckBox which also inherits from ToggleButton. I could use that.

Comment: @GlenThomas - The value property is always true. Replacing the RadioButton with a CheckBox gives the correct behaviour, i.e., toggles between true and false.

Comment: Oh I see, you're trying to use a RadioButton as a CheckBox? RadioButton controls need to be used in groups where only one can be checked and checking one unchecks all the others in the group.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't actually toggle a single RadioButton by clicking it. You may want to use a Checkbox or ToggleButton here.

If you wish to use RadioButtons, you'll have to use at least two of them. Inside the setter for each RadioButton's IsActive property, you have to unset the other buttons.

Other alternatives exist, you can for example bind all the RadioButtons to a single enum property and use a converter. For an example, see:
http://wpftutorial.net/RadioButton.html

Comment: Good to know. Shall use CheckBox